# Identifying the Ancestor of HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf

## hi following is my code and i want to disable the checkbox "scriptCheckBox" (all items),but as of know i could able to disable only one checkbox,pls let me know the solution ##

```
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:TestScript}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stackTestCase" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border x:Name="borderTestCase" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="Transparent" Margin="2,0">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="scriptCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: I have no idea of what you want to accomplish. I don't see any reference to `IsEnabled`, but you talk about disabling something something.

Comment: I was suppose to tell about this checkbox <CheckBox x:Name="scriptCheckBox"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

Comment: you want to disable the CheckBox or want to be checked ??